# SnowFlake: scripting with JSON

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a SnowFlake table which contains JSON data in a `variant` field. This JSON contains an `array` of custom attributes and I know the complete list of possible attributes ahead of time, however, **these attributes can be ordered differently in the JSON array for different rows**.

Let's say it looks like this:

| id | animal | custom_attributes | last_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog | ``` { "attributes": [ { "id": 1, "attName": "feet", "value": 4 }, { "id": 2, "attName": "wings", "value": 0 }] } ``` | 2022-12-31T01:00:00Z |
| 2 | bat | ``` { "attributes": [ { "id": 2, "attName": "wings", "value": 2 }, { "id": 1, "attName": "feet", "value": 2 }] } ``` | 2023-01-11T02:00:00Z |

I'm looking for a way to query it to obtain the following result structure:

| id | animal | feet | wings | last_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog | 4 | 0 | 2022-12-31T01:00:00Z |
| 2 | bat | 2 | 2 | 2023-01-11T02:00:00Z |

The custom attributes should become regular columns.

My SQL knowledge is extremely limited, I rarely work with databases, and this is my first contact with SnowFlake.

Tutorials [like this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial) show me that I could access the JSON array entries by index, but that is not sufficient since the order is not guaranteed in my case, which means this does not work:

```
select 
    id, 
    animal,  
    custom_attributes:attributes[0].value::int as feet,
    custom_attributes:attributes[1].value::int as wings,
from mytable
```

I suspect that it could be done with [SnowFlake scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index), but I fear that I will spend days learning this from scratch before I can write the one query that I need.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is that your JSON is in a name-value pair, rather than an attribute-value.  It'd be easier if the data was provided to you in a true attribute manner.  However, that doesn't mean this can't be done.  It's just more difficult.  The following gives you a way to flatten out your array as records and then pivot the data back into a single record as you need.  You could also use case statements and a group by, if you prefer.  The example uses a cte X just to provide part of the data from your example:

```
with x as (
select parse_json('
{
 "attributes": [
 { 
  "id": 2, 
  "attName": "wings", 
  "value": 2
 },
 { 
  "id": 1, 
  "attName": "feet", 
  "value": 2
 }]
}') as var
), z as (
select y.seq as rec, y.value:attName::string as name, y.value:value::number as value
from x,
lateral flatten(input=>var:attributes) y
)
select * 
  from z
    PIVOT(max(value) FOR name IN ('wings', 'feet'))
      AS p;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to make that work. But I don't really understand the `y.sec as rec` part, what does that do and why is that needed? Also, what is the `max(value)` function used for in the pivot?

Comment: On the lateral flatten, the seq is a column that gets created that represents the original record.  So, with an array that ends up as 2 records, the seq will get you back to your original single record.  If you are applying this to multiple records at a time, it's the only way to know which flattened records relate to what.